# How to get a file's path in Visual Studio solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the best way to get a files in C#. I'm working on an app and i need to use a DLL stored in a folder in my project, however I can't seem to get the right path to it.
[image]

I want to access gsdll32.dll but for now im just hard-coding it. 
Any help?

Comment: Right Click >>> Open Folder in File Explorer

Comment: What's your problem? Can you refer to.dll relatively to app working folder?

Comment: this is whai i have 
                  `string pathToGsDll = @"C:\Users\Ra'ed Al-Araj\Source\Workspaces\Harmony\Src\Harmony.Web.Internet\Ghostscript\gsdll64.dll";`

Comment: I want to change that. and get the relative path to the DLLs

Comment: Add a new Reference to `References` then browse your `DLL` file.

Comment: Add a prebuild script written in msbuild which injects the value of something like string pathToGsDll="$(ProjectDir)Harmony.Web.Internet\G‌​hostscript\gsdll64.d‌​ll" into a C# source file and use that file in the build